# How to deny Execute permission for bunch of stored procedure except some of them?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a login sa and database name called dummy and 40 stored procedures called sp1,sp2,sp3,sp4 etc.,. what is my requirement is i have to access only 2 stored procedure sp1 and sp2 in my login only.other procedure should not to access in my login.Please give any ideas.

Comment: You should try here:   https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=How+to+give+permissions+for+a+specific+Stored+procedures+in+sqlserver

Comment: You are right . As i new to the sqlserver , i cant understand those things.So i came here for step wise advice . anyway thanks for ur reply @TabAlleman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server allows permissions down to the SP level.  Simple go into the stored procedures' properties and assign the permissions the way you need them:
[image]

Comment: Please read up on permissions on the MSDN website.  You need a thorough understanding before trying to make your changes.